# System processes in Unix

Tags: unix, process

One book on Unix programming says

> *The init process never dies. It is a normal user process, not a system process within the kernel, like the swapper, although it does run with superuser privileges.*

What makes a process a system process? Is the system process embedded within the kernel code? Do all system processes run with superuser privileges?

Answer (score 2):

The book probably refers to processes that run entirely in kernel mode. In some versions of Unix, there isn't any actual executable file that implements these process - the kernel "fakes" an entry into the process (and/or thread) list, just so it has something to schedule, and something to account CPU time to. In other implementations, there *is* an executable, but that invokes one system call that never returns.

IOW, it's your first interpretation ("embedded within the kernel code").

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion between kernel mode process and process with super-user privileges.

The book probably wants to say that **init** does not run in kernel mode, but still runs with super-administrative privileges. I hope I am correct.

There are two kind of modes - user and kernel modes. All kind of system calls execute in kernel mode so that they have access to operating system functionality.

Read more on [Protected Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode)